# What is this lapel pin insignia Steve Bannon is wearing?

Tags: united-states, steve-bannon, symbols

What organization is represented by this pin insignia? There appears to be three slightly different designs. It is worn by Steve Bannon, the former Breitbart editor and current trump advisor, during a White House meeting on policy. I was unable to find the significance online.

[image: stevebannon]
[image: lapel pin 1]
[image: lapel pin 2]
[image: lapel pin 3]

Comment: I found a couple more pics where it's a slightly different pin. It's being suggested it's a Secret Service identifier of some kind.

Comment: Comments deleted. Bannon's personality flaws and political views are not relevant to this question. Also, kudos to @Bobson for finding a more neutral picture.

Comment: I thought it might be [here somewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpp0p.jpg) but I don't see it. From The [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/politics/wp/2017/05/26/heres-what-the-pins-that-sheriff-clarke-wears-actually-mean/)

Comment: I asked a friend who would know... it's a secret service day access pin with the great seal and the 6 star surrounding... it designates council between POTUS and NSC. I could put this in the answers... but I have no linkable source. That ok?

Comment: That’s great, thank you. Very spot-on and complete answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That badge was one of a mysterious and ever changing variety of temporary event passes issued to VIPs guarded by the US Secret Service.  It's not unlike a hand stamp at a nightclub, (which helps bouncers know who to admit), or a color coded ticket stub given at a movie theater.

In future decades the current series of USSS badges may become rare collectibles, like old stamps.  At present however, there appears to be no thorough online catalog, perhaps through a spirit of public and official cooperation, and because such badges are believed to be much [more useful to their wearers if there is no such catalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity#Security_through_minority).

---

Note: In the spirit of maintaining minority obscurity, this answer contains no URLs whatsoever to any corroborating sources with pictures.

Comment: There used to be a more specific answer by *Panda* to this Q.  This is an intentionally more vague replacement.